# What's the difference between the two codes?

Tags: c++, vector, insert

What's the difference between the working of the

1. addition of i++, and
2. removal of i++

to the code in reference to the problem: https://leetcode.com/problems/duplicate-zeros/

```
class Solution {
public:
    void duplicateZeros(vector<int>& arr) {
        for(int i=0;i<arr.size();i++)
            if(!arr[i])
            {
                arr.insert(arr.begin()+i+1,0);
                arr.pop_back();
                **//i++;**
            }
    }
};
```

For the input, [1,0,2,3,0,4,5,0]

The output of above code gives [1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0], while uncommenting the (i++) gives [1,0,0,2,3,0,0,4].

So the question is why does the addition of i++ restrict the addition of 0 to only one time?

Answer (score 0):

**Logic without `i++`:**

If you don't do the `i++` inside the loop, the next step will look the `0` you just add and continue to add `0`

**Detail:**

`i` will be incremented by 1 at every step since you do :

```
for(int i=0;i<arr.size();i++) // i = i + 1
```

If we look at the vector and the indices :

```
// arr                = {1,0,2,3,0,4,5,0};
// indices :             0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
```

when `i==1` you update the array to :

```
// arr =               {1,0,0,3,0,4,5,0};
// indices :            0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
```

Then the loop increment `i` to `i==2` but now `arr[2]==0`, so you will add another `0`, and repeat this step until the end of the vector.

---

**Logic with `i++`:**

If you add the `i++` you will skip the `0` you just add and process the rest of the vector as you intended.

**Detail:**

when `i==1` you update the array to

```
// arr =               {1,0,0,3,0,4,5,0};
// indices :            0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
```

But you increment `i` two time, one in the body of the loop and in the loop itself, so **we skip** `i==2`, and we don't get the same problem as before.

So, the next step is `i==3` where `arr[3]==3` so you don't do anything, and so on.

---

I hope it helps

Comment: Does it helps ? If not, pls tell me what you are missing. If it helps, feel free to validate and up-vote